# ASP.NET Core Jwt algorithm

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt

My program is not working. And error says because of security algorithm, but I don't know how it is wrong.

```
public TokenDto CreateToken(UserApp userApp)
{
    var accessTokenExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_tokenOptions.AccessTokenExpiration);
    var refreshTokenExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(_tokenOptions.RefreshTokenExpiration);
    var securityKey = SignService.GetSymmetricSecurityKey(_tokenOptions.SecurityKey);

    SigningCredentials signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(securityKey,SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature);

    JwtSecurityToken jwtSecurityToken = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: _tokenOptions.Issuer,
        expires: accessTokenExpiration,
        notBefore: DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(-5),
        claims: GetClaims(userApp, _tokenOptions.Audience),
        signingCredentials: signingCredentials);

    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

    var token = handler.WriteToken(jwtSecurityToken);

    var tokenDto = new TokenDto
    {
        AccessToken = token,
        RefreshToken = CreateRefreshToken(),
        AccessTokenExpiration = accessTokenExpiration,
        RefreshTokenExpiration = refreshTokenExpiration
    };

    return tokenDto;
}
```

[image]

Comment: The error clearly states that the key (`_tokenOptions.SecurityKey`) should have a size of at least 128 bits. That would be a string of at least 16 characters. As a side note: add text information like errors always as formatted text to the question, not as a screenshot.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to this platform, I'll take your advice into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Using a longer string expression may solve the problem for _tokenOptions.SecurityKey value in appsettings.json

for example:
"SecurityKey":"morestrongersecretkey2023morestrongersecretkey2023morestrongersecretkey2023",